# Get Field ID Value from Json Payload using Java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to get the field_id for the below payload however I am stuck with the below code.
I need the field_id value "70ce3705-0191-4ba4-a635-65108f1c3dde"

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(jsonfilepath));
    JSONObject valid = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("valid");
    JSONArray applications = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("applications_added");
```

Payload:

```
{
    "valid": {
  "applications_added": [
    {
          "id": "f8ca0bda-a10c-4e8d-9c1b-6bfd24e93395",
      "status": "active",
      "custom_fields": [
          {
          "field_id": "70ce3705-0191-4ba4-a635-65108f1c3dde",
          "option_id": "db7bb12d-a26f-413e-b9e5-79af8c28b1e7"
        }

      ]
    }
  ]
}
    }
```

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: org.json.simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code instead of jsonObject.get("applications_added") you sould write valid.get("applications_added")

The complete solution for your problem.

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(jsonfilepath));
    JSONObject valid = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("valid");
    JSONArray applications = (JSONArray) valid.get("applications_added");
    JSONObject application  = (JSONObject)applications.get(0);
    JSONArray custom_fields = (JSONArray) application.get("custom_fields");
    JSONObject custom_field  = (JSONObject)custom_fields.get(0);
    String field_id = (String)custom_field.get("field_id");
```

Comment: but I need field_id

Comment: "applications_added" inside your "valid" json object you can not access it without "valid".

Comment: thats right, but the challenge I am facing is getting the field_id array element within valid

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
    String payload = "your json";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(payload);
        JSONObject valid = jsonObject.getJSONObject("valid");
        JSONArray apps = valid.getJSONArray("applications_added");
        for(int i=0;i<apps.length();i++){
            JSONObject app = apps.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray appFields = app.getJSONArray("custom_fields");
            for(int j=0;j<appFields.length();j++){
                JSONObject field = appFields.getJSONObject(j);
                String fieldId = field.getString("field_id");
                System.out.println(fieldId);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @SurajPrasad I use org.json library.